# "match.text" chainer not found

Tags: cypress

I am trying to assert a text with regex as below:

```
cy.get("voy-vessel-gsis-list-entry").then(() =>  { 
     cy.get('.timeHeader').eq(0).should('match.text','/Departure\s?\((actual|scheduled|communicated)\)'/); 
});
```

And my UI looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, I am asserting that if *the "Departure" message followed by a space and any text inside braces* is visible. But as of now, I am getting the error "*The chainer text was not found. Could not build assertion*" and What am I missing?

Comment: Why don't you use `cy.contains('Departure');`?

Comment: Thank you @manuel Abascal. I missed to write-in question.  my actual regex is `Departure\s?\((actual|scheduled)\)` and I had to validate the OR condition so `cy.contains()` will not suit here.

Comment: The single quotes covering my regex (which I am not supposed to have) made me try different patterns which include adding the escape characters. I now have fixed the regex in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the wrong chainer, you have the wrong regex.

`\\s` gives you literal characters `"\s"`, for a single space it should be  should be `\s`.

`(\\.*)` gives you a capture group starting with a literal `"\"`. I think you are aiming for `\((.*)\)` which is literal opening and closing brackets containing 0 or more characters.

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4Pqtm9/1)

Also the short form of a regex is not quoted.

**Without string delimiters**

```js
cy.get('.timeHeader').eq(0)
  .should('match', /Departure\s\((.*)\)/)
```

**With string delimiters**

```js
cy.get('.timeHeader').eq(0)
  .should('match', new RegExp("Departure\s\((.*)\)"))
```

---

You can also use

```js
cy.get('.timeHeader').eq(0)
  .should('satisfy', (text) => text.startsWith('Departure '))
```

Comment: Thank you @Sarah for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It really says the right thing, there's no chainer `match.text`, the only chainer available is `match` (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions#Text-Content).

Your code should look like:

```js
cy
  .get("voy-vessel-gsis-list-entry")
  .then(() => { 
    cy
      .get('.timeHeader')
      .eq(0)
      .invoke('text')
      .should('match','/Departure\\s(\\.*)/'); 
  });
```

Chainers with "text" token are:

[image]

You can make your IDE help you by adding `/// <reference types="Cypress" />` at the top of your spec file. See Cypress docs [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/ide-integration#Set-up-in-your-Dev-Environment).

Comment: Thank you @Pavelsaman. I have the reference type added but it does not warn me when I write match.text